# Restricted access of function in Haxe?

Tags: actionscript-3, game-engine, haxe

I started playing around with Haxe recently, after using AS3 for quite some time and ran into a problem while writing a very simple game engine:

I have a class called `World`. One of the things the `World` does, is keeping track of all `Entity` objects in the game. I want this list of `Entity` objects to be accessible ONLY from within the engine. The user of the engine should not be able to modify the list directly.

In AS3, I could simply use the `internal` keyword to give access to other classes within the same package. And when that wasn't enough I could define a custom namespace and use it as my access modifier. But Haxe doesn't seem to have either of those.

TL;DR: How can I restrict access of a variable to a specific package/namespace? If not possible, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Haxe 2.11 (nightly build), you can use `@:allow`.

Copied from the [Haxe.org wiki](http://haxe.org/manual/tips_and_tricks):

> @:allow(my.pack) : This will give access to all private fields of a
>   class to all the classes in the package my.pack (and its
>   sub-packages). See Access Control for more info. (since 2.11)

More detailed doc on [Access Control](http://haxe.org/manual/acl).